# How to remove Pandas Index Column when Writting to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Read in CSV string file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',')
```

Sorted it in alphabetical order:

```
 data = data.sort_values("Package", inplace = False)
```

Reseted the Index:

```
data = data.reset_index()
```

Turned off Indexing while writing to CSV:

```
data.to_csv("combined.csv", index=False)
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: Try to use `reset_index(drop=True)` or leave out the `reset_index()` part entirely.

Comment: close your original cdv before write it ?

Comment: @ewz93 done! no luck

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a string formatted for csv. Solution was to save it to csv files before using `pandas` to drop the index column as demonstrated below:

```
def create_file(data, file_name):
   f = open(file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8")
   f.write(data)
   f.close()

create_file(data,  "combined.csv")

data = pd.read_csv("combined.csv", sep=',')
data = data.sort_values("Package", inplace = False)
data.to_csv("combined.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26042), the problem can normally be avoided by skipping calling `reset_index`.

If that doesn't work for you, one alternative solution that was offered is to try the following:

```py
df.to_csv(' file_name.csv ')
df_new = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv').drop(['unnamed 0'],axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for your input, this did not work either.  `to_csv()` requires a dataframe not a string. but saving before dropping the index worked, as shown in my answer